# Training time for dolly-v2-12b on a custom dataset with an A10 gpu

Tags: python, databricks, custom-training, deepspeed, databricks-dolly

Hi I am trying to train the dolly-v2-12b or any of the dolly model using a custom dataset using A10 gpu. I am coding in pycharm, windows os. The task is similar to a Q&A. I am trying to use this as communication assistant that can answer the queries. I have the dataset with more than 10,000 entries each entry might have around 3000 characters.

I wanted to know whether this is possible with the GPU I have and how long will it take to train on the dataset:-training time

UPDATE:
I found [code](https://github.com/ChanCheeKean/DataScience/blob/main/13%20-%20NLP/C08%20-%20Instruct%20GPT%20-%20Dolly.ipynb) and used it to train the model. With my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Graphics card, I was able to train model upto 1billion parameters anything more gets CUDA out of memory error.
I didn't try 8 bit mode yet. I will update when I make it work.

UPDATE:
So I was trying to make the dolly work on 8 bit mode on my pc which is windows system. But the code I find uses [bitsnadbytes](https://pypi.org/project/bitsandbytes/)and [deepspeed](https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed). Somehow I find both of these impossible to install and use on windows systems. If anyone got it please help. I tried the instructions on both of the Github(bitsandbytes and deepspeed). But I am not being able to install it. Is there a workaround or any solution for this.

Comment: I believe you could use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). For reference; I machine translated the Open Assistant dataset which resulted in ~30k entries with much lower number of characters per entry. I can fine tune a 7B, 4bit LLaMa model with my data and 1 epoch takes rougly 1 day. I also have a 3060 with 12 GB vRAM. :^)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  I will try WSL and see how it goes.

Comment: I installed WSL today and tried to configure it on pycharm, but I am using pycharm community edition. It seems only pycharm professional support WSL. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just checked [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) link which says "Available only in PyCharm Professional", sadly you are correct.

Comment: yes, I think It's time to explore online options. I have never tried it so need to do my research. Thinking on starting with colab which I have already worked with. Then may be rty amazon aws. If anyone has tried dolly on online instance please reply.

Comment: For anyone who is following this question. I tried free tier of the AWS cloud and got myself familiar with it. but decided no to use paid GPU.